# DD-WRT router -- very long ssh-login times

Tags: dd-wrt, sshd

I've recently upgraded my DLink router from factory-installed firmware to DD-WRT (version *v24-sp2 std*). I'm quite happy with both the new GUI and the command-line, but I'm puzzled, why it takes almost 8 seconds for an ssh-login -- even from a LAN computer:

```
% time ssh router hostname
DD-WRT v24-sp2 std (c) 2014 NewMedia-NET GmbH
Release: 02/19/14 (SVN revision: 23598)
router
0.023u 0.005s 0:07.98 0.2%      360+1800k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

It takes me only 1-3 seconds to ssh into a FreeBSD computer *behind* this router from the Internet...

What's happening and what I can do? Is it trying to resolve my IP-address -- why would it take so long, it is an IP that this router just handed out (via DHCP)? Thanks!

Invoking ssh with `-vv`, I see the delay after these lines:

```
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
```

Why does it take *8 seconds* for the router to come up with the KEXDH reply? Is its CPU *so* weak? Can I switch to a different algorithm somehow (from the client-side) -- security is of low concern here, because I'm connecting from inside the LAN (of two computers and a printer).

Comment: Does it take as long with `time ssh -4 router hostname`?

Comment: Yes, using -4 makes no difference -- the same 8-second delay after `expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could just be that the CPU in the router isn't very powerful. See [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/116875/how-can-i-disable-encryption-on-openssh) about switching to a faster cipher.

Comment: The only ciphers offered by the ssh-server built into DD-WRT are: aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc. I just tried them all (except 3des-ctr, which my client does not know) -- no appreciable differences in connection times.